# IIS 8.5 .NET Classic Session timeout

Tags: session, iis

I recently moved a web-based barcode scanning system to a new server and a newer version of IIS.

I have been looking through this site's explanations (and several other sites') for an answer to this problem but nothing seems to help the issue.  Logging, IIS or app log, doesn't record when the session expires, only the initiation of a new session.  I feel like I have tried nearly everything, I must be missing something....

Running IIS 8.5 / MS Server 2012 R2 / Amazon EC2 instance

The site is an application running under the default site in IIS.  The application pool is one I set up running .NET Classic and .NET CLR version of "No Managed Code".  The application pool is set for suspend on idle timeout (have tried all settings I believe) and the recycle interval is set for the default 1740 minutes (29 hours).

Users are getting a session timeout after about 30 minutes of inactivity - which is weird as the defaults (if I missed setting one) for these settings are 20 minutes and a 20 minute test does not expire the session.  This is a problem as the scanning guns end up missing scans because the users miss that the session expired.  This causes lot tracking problems down the line.

I have set the application pool idle timeout to 0 for testing.
I have set the asp timeout to 20 hours.
There isn't a web.conf file on the application but there is one on the default site that the app is under.  The web.conf file has

```
<system.web>
     <session.State timeout = "34560" />
</system.web>
```

I installed the asp feature in IIS to attempt to attempt to handle this session timeout issue but this did not affect the behavior.  Some explanations recommend setting session variables on the asp.net feature as well.  This isn't an asp site, it is a index.htm that redirects to a .dll file using ISASPI handlers so the asp.net feature doesn't seem like it is necessary.  Once it hits the .dll all the functions are contained in this .dll.  Perhaps I need to install that feature anyway?

While I am less experienced with IIS, I have not had this problem before the server change.  If I can positively determine that IIS is not the issue then I can push for the other team to address things in the .dll file.

Any assistance is always appreciated.

Respectfully,

SWhite

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be something on the application end not related to IIS settings at all.  No wonder I was getting nowhere.

Thanks for the opportunity to ask.